# Upload File to Amazon S3 in Multiple Parts Using WebClient or HttpClient

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm looking to upload a file to Amazon S3 in multiple parts using C# and either WebClient or HttpClient. The upload process is a 4-step operation:

1. Initiate a multipart upload
2. Create pre-signed URLs for each part
3. Upload the object’s parts
4. Complete multipart upload

I have written methods for step 1, 2, and 4, but I'm not clear as to how to actually upload a file in parts. The parts need to be 5mb in size (or less for the final part), and I've created a method which calculates how many parts the chosen file should be split into.

Here is a working example of uploading a file in a single part with a presigned URL:

```
public void UploadSingleFilePresignedUrl(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    string preSignedUrl = _server.GeneratePreSignedURL(fileName);

    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(preSignedUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
    using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
        using FileStream fileStream = new(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
        HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

In step 2, I've created a list of presigned URLs for each part. I plan to iterate over the list and pass the presigned URL and part number to the method for each part.

In addition, whenever you upload a part, Amazon S3 returns an ETag header in its response. For each part upload, I need to record the part number and the ETag value.

Comment: So you have a complete one file upload function and know the steps for multi-part upload. You have all the pieces already. You now have to search on amazon for the right apis. They have a lot of examples there.

Comment: The software has a client and server component, and I don't want to put the AWS keys on the client (like the API requires). With a pre-signed URL supplied by the server, the client can initiate an upload without needing to have access to the AWS secret keys and gives us more flexibility for our needs. I'm just not sure of how to break a file into multiple parts using C#. Do I use StreamWriter and HttpClient?

Comment: If I understand AWS API correctly you should call getPresignedUrl for each part of the upload and send the list of URLs for each part to the client.

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently. For example, if I have a 20mb video file, I have a method that calculates the filesize and generates 4 presigned URLs and adds them to a list (this part works fine). The question is, how do I split the 20mb video file into four separate 5mb parts?

Comment: Think about splitting as just uploading the part of the file. All you have to do is move the current position of the file to the start of the part and then read the number of bytes in that part.

Comment: What do I use to move the position of the file (Filestream, etc)? In addition, I need to send each part using a distinct pre-signed URL, so I assume once I move the position, I initiate a new upload and send that chunk?

Comment: Use FileStream.Position property to move the current position. You can also read the entire file and upload part by part. Although if you are not sending in parallel what is the point of multi-part upload?